# How to fix footer at the bottom of a component in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to put a footer at the end of my homepage component. In my website, the overflow is made auto only for mobile view with a media query, so the scroll remains hidden for desktop view. I have used all the solutions I could find but nothing helps, the footer is perfectly aligned in desktop view at the bottom, but for mobile view, it is aligned at the end of the screen (not the page). I have no clue how to fix this.

website: https://shivamaima.netlify.com/

git: https://github.com/darwin619/portfolio

```
.homepage {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    min-height:100vh;
    top:0; 
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        overflow: auto;
        height: 100vh;
}
    .footer {

    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You want to fix footer always on on bottom ??

Comment: I need the footer to be at bottom of the page, just like a regular normal footer. But when the page is taller than the screen, then its not working properly.

Comment: try ```position:fixed```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple solutions here. Instead of `bottom: 0` use:

```
margin-top: 100vh;
```

This will set the footer at the bottom of the viewport height.

However, your page has quite a few layout issues, and this is really a band-aid. You should consider utilizing `flexbox`, `min-height`, or `grid` to create a **sticky footer**.

That being said, the solutions for this using react are what they would be in most any circumstance.

The following solutions are preferable because they are "true" dynamic sticky footers. Meaning, the footer stays at the bottom until the main content extends beyond that area, at which point the footer will begin adjusting its position downward:

### The min-height Solution

```css
nav {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
  background: purple;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 170px);
}

footer {
  background: magenta;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <nav>
    Navigation
  </nav>
  <main>
    Page content
  </main>
  <footer> 
    Footer that stays put
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen, we set the **minimum height** of the content to `100vh` minus whatever the combined height (plus padding) happens to be of your `nav` and `content` containers.

This results in a footer that sticks, along with the ability to drop further if the content exceeds the `min-height` value.

The same effect can be accomplished using `flexbox`, which is arguably a more dynamic solution. However, it comes at the expense of an extra container element. We could apply `flex` to `body`, but that is rarely a proper solution:

### The flex box solution

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: lightblue;
}

main {
    padding: 20px;
    background: purple;
    flex: 1;
}

footer {
    background: magenta;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    // Use className instead of class for react (jsx) 
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            Navigation
        </nav>
        <main>
            Main Content Area
        </main>
        <footer> 
            Footer that stays put
        </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
```

### The CSS Grid Solution with min-height

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em 0;
    grid: auto auto 1fr / 10vw 1fr 10vw;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

nav {
    background-color: lightblue;
    grid-column: 2;
    padding: 20px;
}

main {
    background-color: purple;
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 2;
    padding: 20px;
}
footer {
    background-color: magenta;
    align-self: end;
    grid-column: 2;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
// Use className instead of class for react (jsx)
<div class="container">  
      <nav>
          Navigation
      </nav>
      <main>
          Main Content Area
      </main>
      <footer> 
          Footer that stays put
      </footer>
</div>
```

**Note:** Change `class` to `className` if you're working on a react project.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as well, footer still doesn't align properly to the bottom when page is taller than the screen, I guess my layout is really messed up :(

Comment: @ShivamAima Hm. I checked this in my browser, and it moved the footer underneath everything. Did you remove the `bottom: 0;` line of code?

Comment: Yes it does, but not on mobile view, I just can't seem to fix it to the end of page in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

min-height worked for me. I am able to set footer at the bottom even if I try to decrease the height of main which is in b/w the header and footer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).